# MySQL - What's utf8_general_mysql500_ci?

Tags: mysql, collation, mysql-5.5

I just saw that MySQL 5.5 offers `utf8_general_mysql500_ci` as collation.

What is the difference to other collations like `utf8_general_ci`?

Should I better use `utf8_general_mysql500_ci`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As documented under [Changes in MySQL 5.5.21](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.5/en/news-5-5-21.html):

> - New `utf8_general_mysql500_ci` and `ucs2_general_mysql500_ci` collations have been added that preserve the behavior of `utf8_general_ci` and `ucs2_general_ci` from versions of MySQL previous to 5.1.24. Bug #27877 corrected an error in the original collations but introduced an incompatibility for columns that contain German `'ß'` LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S. (As a result of the fix, that character compares equal to characters with which it previously compared different.) A symptom of the problem after upgrading to MySQL 5.1.24 or newer from a version older than 5.1.24 is that [`CHECK TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/check-table.html) produces this error:
>
>   ```
>   Table upgrade required.
>   Please do "REPAIR TABLE `t`" or dump/reload to fix it!
>   ```
>
>   Unfortunately, [`REPAIR TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/repair-table.html) could not fix the problem. The new collations permit older tables created before MySQL 5.1.24 to be upgraded to current versions of MySQL.
>
>   To convert an affected table after a binary upgrade that leaves the table files in place, alter the table to use the new collation. Suppose that the table `t1` contains one or more problematic `utf8` columns. To convert the table at the table level, use a statement like this:
>
>   ```
>   ALTER TABLE t1
>   CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_mysql500_ci;
>   ```
>
>   To apply the change on a column-specific basis, use a statement like this (be sure to repeat the column definition as originally specified except for the `COLLATE` clause):
>
>   ```
>   ALTER TABLE t1
>   MODIFY c1 CHAR(N) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_mysql500_ci;
>   ```
>
>   To upgrade the table using a dump and reload procedure, dump the table using **mysqldump**, modify the [`CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) statement in the dump file to use the new collation, and reload the table.
>
>   After making the appropriate changes, [`CHECK TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/check-table.html) should report no error.
>
>   For more information, see [Checking Whether Tables or Indexes Must Be Rebuilt](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/checking-table-incompatibilities.html), and [Rebuilding or Repairing Tables or Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/rebuilding-tables.html). (Bug #43593, Bug #11752408)